Git: Recover deleted files from previous commit - ‘show’ not working
I’m new to git and don’t have a programming background - apologies for my ignorance.
Some background: I’m using git to sync a folder from my PC and iPad. To do this i made a GitHub repository which syncs to the folder on my PC via an application plugin (obsidian git). As this plugin isn’t recommended for iPad, I took a more manual approach and cloned the repo to a local folder on my iPad and added the GitHub repo as a remote repo. I use A-shell on the iPad to run git commands via libgit2 (lg2) which came preinstalled in A-shell.
This workflow was working fine until a merge conflict emerged on my iPad, preventing me from pulling from or pushing to the remote repo (I think all of the commits i tried to make on my iPad during this period failed). I solved this merge conflict with a .gitignore file that excludes the file that created the conflict (which I don’t want to sync across devices anyway). Once the conflict was resolved I pulled from the remote repo before committing my local repo which deleted a few local files, some of which I don’t remember their name. I’m worried that these files are now unrecoverable because the commit attempts made from my iPad when the conflict existed don’t appear in the log history.
I tried inspecting the contents of the commits in my log to see if any of them contain references to these files. To do this I used ‘lg2 log’ to view the commit history and get the commit hashes and then ‘lg2 show ’ but this command fails with the error:
“Command not found: show”
Why would libgit2 not include the command ‘show’? Is there a beginner friendly way to add this command?
If none of the previous commits contain a reference to these deleted files is there any way I can recover them?
I imagine there are many ways in which I messed up here, can anyone offer pointers on how to avoid making mistakes like this in the future?
Thank you!

Using plain old gir, you could check git reflog. That should give you the commits on which HEAD has been the last few times (and with a few it could mean a few hundred as garbage collection waits for a while to collect stuff only pointed at from reflog).

Using ‘git’ always returns “git: command not found”. ‘Lg2 reflog’ returns the error “command not found: reflog”
